# jQuery - Multiply the value in the form with (predefined) factors given by checkbox values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cakephp-3.0

I have a string which is a sequence of combinations like this: "AB BCD C AD ABCD...".

A, B, C and D are the factors, let's say 2, 3, 4 and 5.

I need to calculate the value `total`, which is a product of initial value (10 or 20 in the html example below) and these factors.

The combination of factors should be selected by user via checking the corresponding boxes, but the combination they select should be contained in the string above. If not, the user should have an option to select the allowed combination from the drop-down menu. The latter action should check the corresponding boxes automatically and thus calculate the needed value of `total`.

I need this repeated many times in the form and I got stuck at the stage of reading different initial values of `total` from the html attribute "value". Current version ignores that since I set `total = 10` in jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {        
    $(".factor-checkbox").click(function(event) {
        var $section = $(this).closest(".section"),
            total = 10;
        $section.find("input:checked").each(function() {
            total *= parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        $section.find('.result').val(total);
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="A" value="2" class="factor-checkbox">A</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="B" value="3" class="factor-checkbox">B</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="C" value="4" class="factor-checkbox">C</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="D" value="5" class="factor-checkbox">D</label>

    <label>Result <input type="text"  value="10" class="result"></label>
    
</div>

<div class="section">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="A" value="2" class="factor-checkbox">A</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="B" value="3" class="factor-checkbox">B</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="C" value="4" class="factor-checkbox">C</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="D" value="5" class="factor-checkbox">D</label>

    <label>Result <input type="text" value="20" class="result"></label>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="A" value="2" class="factor-checkbox">A</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="B" value="3" class="factor-checkbox">B</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="C" value="4" class="factor-checkbox">C</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="D" value="5" class="factor-checkbox">D</label>

    <!-- select box with available combinations (can be baked through JS) -->
    <select style="display:none" class='helperBox'>
        <option val=''>Available Combos</option>
        <option val='AB'>AB</option>
        <option val='BCD'>BCD</option>
        <option val='C'>C</option>
        <option val='AD'>AD</option>
        <option val='ABCD'>ABCD</option>
     </select>        
     <label>Result <input type="text"  value="10" class="result"></label>    
</div>

<div class="section">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="A" value="2" class="factor-checkbox">A</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="B" value="3" class="factor-checkbox">B</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="C" value="4" class="factor-checkbox">C</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="D" value="5" class="factor-checkbox">D</label>
    <select style="display:none" class='helperBox'>
        <option val=''>Available Combos</option>
        <option val='AB'>AB</option>
        <option val='BCD'>BCD</option>
        <option val='C'>C</option>
        <option val='AD'>AD</option>
        <option val='ABCD'>ABCD</option>
      </select>            
    <label>Result <input type="text" value="20" class="result"></label>    
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {        

    // combo list
    var combos = ['AB', 'BCD', 'C', 'AD', 'ABCD'];

    $(".factor-checkbox").click(function(event) {
        var $section = $(this).closest(".section");
        var $total = $section.find('.result');
        total = calculateTotal($section);        
        $total.val(total);
    });       

    // combo selection box logic
    $('.helperBox').change(function(){      
        var $section = $(this).closest(".section");
        var $options = $section.find("input[type=checkbox]");
        var selectedCombo = $(this).val();          // current selected value
        var selectionArray = selectedCombo.split('');   // break current selected value into names

            //iterate available options
        $options.each(function(i,child){      

            // if name is present check it, else uncheck it
            if($.inArray(child.name,selectionArray) > -1) {         
                $(child).prop('checked',true);          
            } else {
                $(child).prop('checked',false);
            }
        })

        // set new total and hide the combination select box
        var $total = $section.find('.result');
        total = calculateTotal($section);        
        $total.val(total);
        $(this).hide();
    });

    function calculateTotal($section) {
        var $total = $section.find('.result');

        // get default value of input field
        total = parseInt($total.attr('value'));        

        // if allowed calulate total, elseshow help selection  
        if(validateCombo($section) > -1) {              
            $section.find("input:checked").each(function() {      
            total *= parseInt($(this).val());
            });         
        } else {
            $section.find('.helperBox').show();
        }

        return total;
    }

    // check if selected combination is allowed, returns -1 if not allowed
    function validateCombo(parent) {
        var comboString = '';      

      parent.find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(i,child){
        if($(child).is(':checked'))
            comboString += child.name;
      });      
      return $.inArray(comboString,combos);
    }               
});
```

The basic idea is to check if the selected combination is allowed (is present in combination "AB BCD C AD ABCD..."). If the combination is not present in the selection we need to show the user a selection box with available combinations.

[See on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L1n6k17d/4/)

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what i needed. Thank you very much! Will try to implement everything.

Comment: Would it possible in your solution to have variable `combos` different for each section and read it from the options of the corresponding `helperBox` or from the string which will have different values for different sections as I will iterate in the form?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {        
        $(".factor-checkbox").click(function(event) {
            var $section = $(this).closest(".section");
          
            if ($section.find("input:checked").length>0)
            { 
               total = $section.find('.result').val();
               initial = total;
              
             
            $section.find("input:checked").each(function() {
                total *= parseInt($(this).val());
            });
            $section.find('.result').val(total);
            }else {
            total = $section.find('.result').val(initial);
            }
            
        });
        });
```

```css
input.initial{

}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="section">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="A" value="2" class="factor-checkbox">A</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="B" value="3" class="factor-checkbox">B</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="C" value="4" class="factor-checkbox">C</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="D" value="5" class="factor-checkbox">D</label>

        <label>Result <input type="text"   value="10" class="result">
        
        </label>
        
    </div>

    <div class="section">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="A" value="2" class="factor-checkbox">A</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="B" value="3" class="factor-checkbox">B</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="C" value="4" class="factor-checkbox">C</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="D" value="5" class="factor-checkbox">D</label>

        <label>Result <input type="text"  value="20" class="result">
      
        </label>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: Nice, thank you, but when the box is unchecked, Result does not show the initial value.

Comment: it works only if you check and uncheck single box. Try to check boxes A and B and then uncheck them. The Result will be wrong.